# Getting java.io.IOException: Trying to upload file XXXXXX to path XXXXX but that is a directory. While using net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient

Tags: java, sftp, sshj

Getting this exception while doing SFTP to remote server

Following is stack trace of exception

```
java.io.IOException: Trying to upload file Test.pdf to path /MyFolder/NewTest/Test.pdf but that is a directory
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.prepareFile(SFTPFileTransfer.java:310)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.uploadFile(SFTPFileTransfer.java:228)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:183)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.access$100(SFTPFileTransfer.java:166)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:64)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.put(SFTPClient.java:244)
```

Following is code snippet that is being used

```
String localFile = "D:/SFTPFiles/Test.pdf";
String remoteFilePath = "/MyFolder/NewTest";

SSHClient sshClient = new SSHClient();
sshClient.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
sshClient.connect(remoteHost);
sshClient.authPassword(downloadUserName, password);
SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();
FileSystemFile fileSystemFile = new FileSystemFile(localFile);
sftpClient.put(fileSystemFile, remoteFilePath);
sftpClient.close();
sshClient.disconnect();
```

I have checked and ensured that file on local server exists. Directories on remote server are also present. Have also tried using StatefulSFTPClient. Also no directory of same name as that of file name exists on remote server.

Detailed logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Trying to upload file Test.pdf to path MyFolder/NewTest/Test.pdf but that is a directory
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.prepareFile(SFTPFileTransfer.java:310)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.uploadFile(SFTPFileTransfer.java:228)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:183)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.access$100(SFTPFileTransfer.java:166)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:64)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.put(SFTPClient.java:244)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl.uploadFileToCBCKPA(NYCServiceImpl.java:241)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c952ae3c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b7522d71.uploadFileToCBCKPA(<generated>)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController.getProgressNYC(NYCController.java:66)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a84daf5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e05a8618.getProgressNYC(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.testing.commons.MyFilter.doFilterInternal(MyFilter.java:19)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.testing.service.jwt.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
```

For No such file:

```
net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPException: No such file
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.Response.error(Response.java:140)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.Response.ensurePacketTypeIs(Response.java:117)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.open(SFTPEngine.java:143)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPEngine.open(SFTPEngine.java:149)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.uploadFile(SFTPFileTransfer.java:233)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:183)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer$Uploader.access$100(SFTPFileTransfer.java:166)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPFileTransfer.upload(SFTPFileTransfer.java:64)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient.put(SFTPClient.java:244)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl.uploadFileToCBCKPA(NYCServiceImpl.java:241)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c952ae3c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$60abb72e.uploadFileToCBCKPA(<generated>)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController.getProgressNYC(NYCController.java:66)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a84daf5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.testing.user.prjct.NYCController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e621918.getProgressNYC(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
```

WinScp successful file transfer logs

```
. 2021-03-23 17:48:16.920 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.351 Getting current directory name.
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.351 Listing directory "/MyFolder/NewTest".
> 2021-03-23 17:48:17.351 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 23, Number: 1547
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.351 Sent 27 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1284
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 Discarding reserved response
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.352 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Received 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Read 4 bytes (10 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Read 10 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 1547
> 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 1804
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.363 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.372 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Received 227 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Read 4 bytes (223 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Read 223 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 223, Number: 1804
> 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 2060
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Read file 'panImage.jpg' from listing
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Read file 'TEST.pdf' from listing
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.373 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Received 32 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Read 4 bytes (28 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Read 28 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 2060
< 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Status code: 1
> 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 2308
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 panImage.jpg;-;926778;2021-03-22T13:28:50.000Z;3;"user" [0];"group" [0];-w--w--w-;1
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.383 TEST.pdf;-;1057344;2021-03-22T13:35:46.000Z;3;"user" [0];"group" [0];-w--w--w-;1
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.384 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:17.608 Session upkeep

. 2021-03-23 17:48:18.457 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:18.457 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:18.970 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:19.485 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:19.985 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:20.499 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:20.499 Received 28 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:20.999 Session upkeep

. 2021-03-23 17:48:26.541 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.040 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.177 Size of 1 local files/folders calculated as 11
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.218 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/MyFolder/NewTest/" - total size: 11
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.218   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.218   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.218   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 File: 'D:\Work\kyc\Test2.txt' [2021-03-23T09:42:55.891Z] [11]
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 Copying "D:\Work\kyc\Test2.txt" to remote directory started.
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 Opening remote file.
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 49, Number: 2563
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.221 Sent 53 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2308
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 Discarding reserved response
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.222 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.239 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.239 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.240 Received 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.240 Read 4 bytes (10 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.240 Read 10 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.240 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 2563
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.586 Write request offset: 0, len: 11
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 33, Number: 3078
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Sent 37 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 3332
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 45, Number: 2825
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Sent 49 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.587 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Received 56 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Read 4 bytes (52 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Read 24 bytes (28 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 3078
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.604 Status code: 0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 3332
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Status code: 0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Preserving timestamp [2021-03-23T09:42:55.000Z]
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.605 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Received 28 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 2825
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Status code: 0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.621 Transfer done: 'D:\Work\kyc\Test2.txt' => '/MyFolder/NewTest/Test2.txt' [11]
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 Copying finished: Transferred: 11, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 0/s
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 Listing directory "/MyFolder/NewTest".
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 23, Number: 3595
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 Sent 27 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.622 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Received 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Read 4 bytes (10 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Read 10 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 10, Number: 3595
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 3852
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.640 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Received 332 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Read 4 bytes (328 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Read 328 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 328, Number: 3852
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 10, Number: 4108
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Read file 'panImage.jpg' from listing
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Read file 'TEST.pdf' from listing
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Read file 'Test2.txt' from listing
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.652 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Received 32 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Read 4 bytes (28 pending)
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Read 28 bytes (0 pending)
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 4108
< 2021-03-23 17:48:27.662 Status code: 1
> 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 10, Number: 4356
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 Sent 14 bytes
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 panImage.jpg;-;926778;2021-03-22T13:28:50.000Z;3;"user" [0];"group" [0];-w--w--w-;1
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 TEST.pdf;-;1057344;2021-03-22T13:35:46.000Z;3;"user" [0];"group" [0];-w--w--w-;1
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 Test2.txt;-;11;2021-03-23T09:42:55.000Z;3;"user" [0];"group" [0];-w--w--w-;1
. 2021-03-23 17:48:27.663 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T05:30:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-03-23 17:48:28.038 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:28.552 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:29.070 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:29.589 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:29.589 Detected network event
. 2021-03-23 17:48:30.087 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:30.589 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:31.091 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:31.593 Session upkeep
. 2021-03-23 17:48:31.593 Received 28 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dest` argument of the [`SFTPClient.put`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.hierynomus/sshj/latest/net/schmizz/sshj/sftp/SFTPClient.html#put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is a path to the *file*, not path to the destination *directory*. The error message is rather clear about that.

So, like this:

```
String remoteFilePath = "/MyFolder/NewTest/Test.pdf";
```